# How to implement search functionality on a forum-like site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I would like your advice for the best way to implement the following application.

The architecture that we're going to be using is the following:

1. ASP .Net MVC 2
2. Entity Framework 4
3. SQL Server 2008

The application is a forum-like kind of site in which there will be static content and content added by the site's registered users.

The requirements would be the following:

- The site needs to be language localizable (easy to do)
- The users should be able to search for content in both the static one and what others have entered in their preferred language. I guess that for all "western" languages it would not be a problem, but I'm thinking about languages like Russian, Chinese, Hebrew, or any that doesn't use the western alphabet.

So my questions would be:

- What would be the best way to store the users' entries? Should it be the SQL Server database or other kind of repository to make the text search more effective and efficient?
- What would be the best tool to use for this job? I know SQL Server has some kind of Text Search or, should I use another one?
- What would be the best way to implement SO's functionality that when you entered your new question's Title you get a few suggestions? (I really love that)  :)

Everything and anything that you can suggest will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please guys, I could really use some help with this, I have some ideas but I'm sure that with some guidance my life would me so much easier .... anyone?